# json_encode output in PHP not giving the data a label so it can be accessed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I am currently trying to pull existing data from my database to use on a page in real time,
I have a PHP file called json.php that use's the following code.

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Which then outputs.

```
[
    {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "1",
    "img": "1.jpg"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "2",
    "img": "2.png"
}
]
```

But as Im trying to learn online every example I see seems to have a label for each 'object' from the JSON then is called using something like,

```
    json.label.title
```

How comes the PHP function doesn't print out a label so I can access the data in jQuery? Or have I done something wrong with my tables in MySQL?

As I said above I have tried researching online to learn how to do this but on every example I keep running into this problem.

Comment: That's just a valid JSON formatted string you output. Also note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: it's called a `key` not a `label`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON represents an array holding objects.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
    json[i].title; // your value
```

`[...]` is an array with numeric indexes (from `0` to `array.length - 1`) and `{...}` an object with string labels.

Comment: I dont fully understand I am afraid. So json[1].title should print "1", is that correct?

Comment: @Trendee No. `2`. `json[0].title` should print `1`.

Comment: Ah! I think I understand now. But it doesnt seem to be working. This http://jsfiddle.net/Pw32q/ Prints out Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined - EDIT, I tried the code that dianuj suggested and I think it interfered with your suggestion, I removed it and it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: @Trendee what about copying the whole url of your script in the fiddle? The fiddle has no crystal ball to see from which server to download the json.php